# DAX Power BI Matrix visual

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a requirement, i have to transform a tabular information to below output format.

[image: Table]

What i have done is :

- created measured for financial measure Revenue, Volume and cost for each category i.e. volume staying, volume exiting and volume by OTHERS
- Used SWITCH measure to have category into columns and financial measure into rows
- UNPIVOT i cannot do as as more than 5Millon rows are there
- With exisitng setup it was taking more time to load the viusal as there are around 22 financial measures

[image: Tried Option]

Thank you for checking this post.

Comment: hi, I think can do it with DAX. Just confirm one question first: in INPUT table, do you have any columns to define the staying/leaving/others?

Comment: Hi, there thanks for replying, had found a way via DAX code to fix the problem